# How can I hide my profile on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

I am planning to hide my profile on one of the Stack Exchange sites. I am not asking to hide my network profile. While that would be my main goal, but I know that is not possible.

I want no one can click on my username to see my profile page. That way I have effectively disabled my network profile. I have seen a couple of users have done this.

[image]

See that no one can click on the user name above. I understand it can happen if the user is deleted. But I have seen other users which were relatively newer like asked question yesterday but there usernames were not clickable.

1. Is this feature available somewhere?
2. If not do I have to request it on this particular Stack Exchange site to make my profile hidden? If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you want to hide your profile? Note that the "couple of users" you've seen do this have all done so through content disassociation (which can happen as a result of user deletion but not necessarily), but their profiles don't get "hidden".

Comment: Another option is to create brand new account (using a different OpenID provider), ask to merge your existing account on the specific site into that account then delete it. You can then use that new account without anyone knowing it's you. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd awesome solution! so after merging, the two user names remain different even after merge? how about the reputation? is it shared or not.

Comment: Cheers @Dave, I added more details as a new answer. :)

Comment: *"I have seen other users which were relatively newer like asked question yesterday but there usernames were not clickable"* -- are you sure those were not migrated questions, for which the user had not (yet?) visited the target site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "hidden account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268158/what-is-a-hidden-account)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do that for all your posts is to request deletion of your account on that site. There is no other way to achieve this.

If you only want to do this on a specific post, you can ask for this post to be disassociated from your user.

Comment: Regarding requesting it on one specific post: will it has the same user name as mine, will it show my reputation? will the reputation be counted against me

Comment: It will look exactly like the image in your question, not linked and with a "user1234" instead of your user name. You will lose all the reputation you earned from that post.

Comment: how will I request it btw? and will I get notification on that post?

Comment: You can contact SE using the ["contact us" link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) at the bottom of the page.