# What is a "hidden account"?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, hidden-communities

In my profile I saw this:

> Accounts (48) - 1 hidden account

as seen in this image:

> [image: Accounts (48) - 1 hidden account]

So, what is this "hidden account"? And how do I see it?

Comment: Well, it was introduced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) (under "The broader context" section) - but agree it's not trivial to understand what this is, or find that post

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A hidden account is one that is...well.. hidden from view. You can see this in the **Edit Profile & Settings**, then click on **Hide Communities**, there should be two lists - **Visible Communities** and **Hidden Communities** and options to hide and unhide communities.

To see your complete list, go to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts) - and all memberships are shown.

Related: [Profile is still counting a hidden community that no longer exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267501/306364)