# Why is the hide communities tab not visible on the Network Profile?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, network-profile, hidden-communities

I wanted to make a community visible again and my first idea was to go the network profile to do it, but found there no option or tab to do so.

After seeing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268159/331810), I then went to *some* account and did it.

Why is it not available in the Network Profile?

At a first glance, it seems to me like it should be its place there, and not in the individual accounts (at least not only)...

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is – there is *no information at all* which you can update in the Network Profile. You can update your profile by copying it from one of your per-site profiles, that's about it. While the option is definitely connected to the Network Profile, it would be confusing to have that as the only option you could edit there.

I guess that if Stack Exchange ever decides to move the maintenance of other network-wide options (logins, flair) to the Network Profile, they will migrate the hide/show communities option there as well.

Comment: I guess *no information at all* is the key here :)