# How do I hide a community from my network profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile, hidden-communities

I want to hide an account from my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4030991/steven-vascellaro).

I would like to reference my Stack Exchange profile in a professional setting. I do not want one of my accounts publically displayed for employers to see.

I've heard that it's possible to add accounts to a list of hidden communities, but I haven't been able to find any way to add them from my network profile page.

**How can I hide a community from my Network Profile?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[User Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) -> [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) -> [Hide Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current)**

You can edit your hidden communities while on any Stack Exchange community, with the (somewhat ironic) exception of [StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281076/351462) and Area 51.

[image: Menu for hiding communities]

Comment: This page says “Showing 12 community out of 29 visible communities”. I can not see how to hide the other 17 communities.