# How can a user earn almost 100 reputation points with no upvoted questions and no profiles on other sites?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus, hidden-communities

This profile [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/44200/user345738380?tab=profile) got almost 100 reputation points & 30 votes casted & no upvoted questions.

So there is no way to achieve 100 reputation points.

It only joined in movies community only.

please explain me how this profile got this many reputations with no upvoted post?

Comment: He received [Association bonus](/q/141648/), check his [reputation history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/44200/user345738380?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus). They have an account on another site with >= 200 rep, so they start out at 101 on every other site.

Ah... But you don't see any other sites in their profile. Well, turns out [they've hidden them all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267121/hiding-sites-from-the-main-stackexchange-com-profile-page). Sneaky!

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the user's profile > Activity > reputation, you can see the user's reputation history:

[image]

The user got an association bonus of 100 reputation points. If you have more than 200 reputation points on one Stack Exchange site, you get an association bonus on all sites (including the one where you earned the 200 reputation). This is meant so that you don't have to go through new user restrictions every time you create an account on a new site, so you can post images, comment, upvote etc directly when you create an account if you're trusted on other sites. You can read more about the association bonus [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/349538).

In this specific case, the user chose to [hide their Movies & TV account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268158/349538) so only that user and moderators can see the user's complete account from Movies & TV (or see the user's Movies & TV account from another site).