# Why is a site not showing in the Network Profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

When looking at the network profile of user [Valorum](https://stackexchange.com/users/3776439/valorum), I notice that they have 300k rep on SciFi.SE, but it doesn't show up on their accounts tab.

Even stranger, if you go to their profile on Literature.SE, the communities sidebar doesn't list SciFi and their profile on SciFi.SE doesn't list any other sites. Here are some photos because my English is lacking.

Sidebar of [SciFi profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum):

[image: Sidebar of SciFi.SE profile]

SideBar of [Literature profile](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/262/valorum):

[image: Sidebar of Literature profile]

[Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3776439/valorum):

[image]

Why did this happen? Is it just me? Is this a bug? I don't think it's caching. The system had plenty of time.

Comment: the profile on lit.se is because they have choose to hide the communities

Comment: @redhand Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. Does that also explain the network profile?

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ I don't think they can hide it in se.com but I am not sure

Comment: @Pang If you go to the questions tab on their Network Profile, you can see questions from both lit and scifi.

Comment: @Pang that is not necessary. go to the posts from n/w profile

Comment: @Pang sure, although redhand explained the part about the communities not appearing in the sidebar.

Comment: lol the way you type "literature" is "lit" a*

Comment: They could have created two independent accounts, or marked their SFF profile as [hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268159/270345).

Comment: Also, unrelatedly, while there's no risk that anyone but an extreme oldtimer would get confused.... I was like "Wait, why is there someone with a CHAOS symbol" when I saw your username

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - It occurs to me that it's a bit bloody pointless being able to hide communities if it's acceptable for someone to ask on Meta why a particular user is hiding those communities and for a mod to to then explain that they're hiding them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [choose to hide specific communities from your network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267121/hiding-sites-from-the-main-stackexchange-com-profile-page) for various reasons. He has chosen to hide SFF.

As per the blurb for the page

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts. It does not, however, mean your activity is private.

So it means that if there's a ponies.stackexchange.com, and its hidden, people won't see it in your communities list, but someone who's a fellow user on the site will see you there.

Comment: Questions from SciFi.SE still show up on his Top Network Questions/Answers. I don't know if that's the same thing as Top Network Posts though,

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ that is actually kind of a bug which annoys many people.

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ posts from hidden communities are hidden from the “Top Network Posts” on *site* profiles, but not the *network* profile. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277279/307988